# Rails on Windows File Upload without gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, file-upload

I've been struggling for over a dozen hours trying to get File Upload to work on my own, and I don't think I can do it on my own. After several hours, I was unable to make Paperclip or Carrierwave work, likely because I'm using windows, at least for the short term. I spent several more hours trying to manually install them. I then spent several hours trying to make File Upload work without gems. I've worked through each error, and I think I'm very close. I'm going to post all my information. Trail and error has made the code messy, but I suspect there's only one or two problems left. I'm working off the blog scaffold. I have class Articles, with class Comments belonging to Articles, trying to attach the files to Articles.

My current error when trying to upload.

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ArticlesController#create
Picture(#46001052) expected, got ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile(#29170272)
```

Here's the line of error from the article_controller.rb.

```
@article = Article.new(article_params)
```

I find it strange that it expects #46001052 but receives a file with #29170272

Here's my article_controller.rb. I suspect this is the problem. The def upload I don't think is getting used, and that it's just a leftover from trail and error. I get the same error when I remove it.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

http_basic_authenticate_with name: "Goose", password: "123456",
except: [:index, :show, :new, :create]

def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def create
@article = Article.new(article_params)
if @article.save
redirect_to @article
else
render 'new'
end
end

def show
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def index
@articles = Article.all
end

def edit
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@article = Article.find(params[:id])

if @article.update(article_params)
redirect_to @article
else
render 'edit'
end
end

def destroy
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article.destroy
redirect_to articles_path
end

def upload
uploaded_io = params[:article][:picture]
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
end

private
def article_params
params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :picture)
end

end
```

I also made a pictures_controller.rb with some similar stuff just in case. Will post if asked.

Here's my article.rb model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_one :picture, dependent: :destroy
validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 5 }

  end
```

Here's my picture.rb model

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :article
end
```

Here's my _form. I feel pretty confident this is right.

```
<%= form_for @article, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
  this article from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<p>
<%= f.text_field :title , :size => "60X10" %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.text_area :text , :size => "60x10" %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.file_field :picture %>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.submit "Talk" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Here's my routes.rb. I split up :uploads from :comments to be safe, but I get the same error either way.

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

resources :articles do
resources :comments
end

resources :articles do
resources :uploads
end
root 'welcome#index'
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'welcome/index'
```

I read somewhere to add a column to my table, so I added this migration called add_new_column_to_my_table.rb

```
class AddNewColumnToMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
self.up
add_column :articles, :new_column, :picture
end

end
end
```

I also made a create_pictures.rb migration.

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :pictures do |t|
  t.string :image
  t.references :article, index: true
end
end
end
```

I figured out how to save files to a directory, and even give that file a unique file name that is the timestamp when it was created, but I haven't figured out how to link that file to it's matching article. Just saving that time at the time I create the file as a variable would work, but controllers apparently aren't a good place to do this.

I've poured my mind into this, and it's become clear that I'm going to need help. I hope you have an easier time with this problem than I've been having.

UPDATE: By request, here is my schema.rb code, which does look suspect.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140630023622) do
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
t.string   "commenter"
t.text     "body"
t.integer  "article_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"

create_table "data_files", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "pictures", force: true do |t|
t.string "image"
end

create_table "uploads", force: true do |t|
t.string   "timestamp"
t.text     "fileid"
t.integer  "article_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "uploads", ["article_id"], name: "index_uploads_on_article_id"

end
```

Comment: this is a great question and is something that I am having an issue with, were you able to solve it?

Comment: @BenSmith This was long ago when I first started programming, but no. I ultimately found the Rails community to be very Mac-centric so I moved on to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have this problem before you ran you AddNewColumnToMyTable migration? If not, I see two problems. First the migration you are trying to write should look like this:

```
class AddNewColumnToMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :picture, :string
  end
end
```

That would tell the database to add a string column called picture to the articles schema. The second problem is that you are adding "picture" to a model that already has a relation to a model named picture. That means the migration needs to have a different name for picture:

```
class AddNewColumnToMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :picture_id, :string
  end
end
```

If that doesn't work, please post your schema.rb file.

Comment: No luck, same error. Did you want me to create a controller called AddNewColumnToMyTable_controller.rb with the second block of code, cause that's what I did.

Comment: Is that your entire schema.rb file? You don't even have an articles table in there.

Comment: Left this out. //ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140630023622) do

Comment: When you ran your AddNewColumnToMyTable migration, you should have gotten an error about not having a table called articles. Did you run rake db:migrate in your terminal after creating your AddNewColumnToMyTable migration?

Comment: Well anyways you need to create an articles table

Answer (score 0):

[**Paperclip**](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

We always use the likes of `Paperclip` - so I'll love to provide ways to solve your "compatibility" issue on Windows if that's okay

By default, `Paperclip` will work on any platform, as it does not *rely* on any external dependencies; your problem will likely be with Paperclip's integration with `ImageMagick` (very tricky to get right):

--

**ImageMagick**

ImageMagick is the processor which allows Paperclip to change different backend options for your images. It is what allows the resizing, cropping & other image-changing processes to be performed when you upload an image.

It's very tricky to get `ImageMagick` to work with Windows. We've found the best way is to use the following version:

> [ImageMagick 6.8.7 Q16 (32 bit)](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.7-0-Q16-x86-dll.exe)

There's an [excellent resource here](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/) to download previous versions of ImageMagick

--

Considering you get your `Paperclip` gem installed & migrated - you should be able to upload with Paperclip; regardless of what happens with other parts of the system

Comment: I was having trouble with paperclip being recognized by the terminal before I even installed ImageMagick, and I did follow a guide walking me through paperclip and imagemagick compatibility.

Comment: Okay thanks for the comment! Do you have any error you could refer me to? I want to get Paperclip fixed for you - it's far better than using a homebrew upload system